# Being redirected to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi by cpanel

Tags: apache, .htaccess, server, cpanel

I have a website with domain: http://www.example.com
This resolves fine. I don't have SSL setup for my domain.
However if I try to go to:
http**s**://www.example.com
I get redirected to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

I understand that this is a cpanel redirect however I don't know how to stop it. Ideally I would like the site to redirect to the http version. 
I know that I could do this with an htaccess file, however the cpanel redirect is exceuting before it reaches the htaccess file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not installed SSL on your domain so you can not redirect your https to http version, You will have to install self signed SSL on your domain to get this resolve. Because cpanel has SSL entry in httpd configuration with DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache/htdocs and due to that https is showing defaultwebpage.